# Which hotel has the most stayings?

Tags: oracle

I am pretty new at Oracle, and I am doing some examples which I found on one of the websites to learn something new. One of the tasks is to get from tables, which hotel has the most stayings. I find this one problem realy complex and I can not solve it by myself, so I Will be happy if someone could help me with soultion and explanation why is is that way.

I understood that question in that way, that you have to connect `VISITOR`, `VISITED`, `HOTEL`, `OWNING` and `OWNER` tables.

To explain. `OWNING` table is connecting `OWNERs` with their `HOTELs` and `VISITED` table is connecting `VISITORs` with `HOTEL` in which they stayed.

This are my tables for that example: [Pastebin link to my example](http://pastebin.com/phTyKSRJ).

What I have tried so far is:

```
SELECT visitor.id, visitor.name, visitor.surname, hotel.name
FROM visitor
LEFT JOIN visiting
ON visitor.id = visiting.tk_visitor
LEFT JOIN hotel
ON hotel.id = visiting.tk_hotel
ORDER BY hotel.id ASC;
```

This is connecting three tables, so I get Visitors and Hotels connected in one table, but i can't go further.

I hope that Will be able to help me, so I can learn something new on that example.

Thanks in addition!

Comment: Oracle and MySQL are not the same thing. Which are you using?

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking for in results. In your statement I only see you are joining two tables, not three...

Comment: @Barmar I am using ORACLE

Comment: @ryekayo, `vistor LEFT JOIN visiting LEFT JOIN hotel` looks like three tables to me.

Comment: Why do you need to go further? You don't need to know anything about owners to answer which hotel has the most stayings.

Comment: @ryekayo You are right, I connected two tables via third table which is connecting both of them thorugh foreign key. 
The result should be name of hotel which has the most guest aka stayings.

Comment: @JohnBolling I see it now, i misread it

Comment: @HC1122, are you looking for the hotel with the largest number of distinct guests (visitors), or the one with the largest number of total visits?  If the latter, then why are you selecting anything about individual visitors?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well as I counted by myself one of the hotels has like 3 or 4 Visitors, so I want that hotel to be displayed as the most visited hotel.
I am selecting individual visitors because I thought I need to count how many of them stayed in which hotel. I don't know. I am working in ORACLE for like 10 days so I am learning now.

Comment: @Barmar So how else can I get then who or how much visitors were in hotels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which hotel has the most stayings[?]

Each visit corresponds to one row in table `visited`, therefore you want to count rows of `visited` on a per-hotel basis.  That's this:

```
select tk_hotel, count(*) as visits
FROM visited
GROUP BY tk_hotel
```

If you want only the one (one of the ones) with the most visits then you can order the results by visit count, and take only the first.  To get the *name* of the hotel instead of just its id, you should join the previous result to the `hotel` table:

```
SELECT h.name, mv.visits
FROM (
    SELECT tk_hotel, count(*) as visits
    FROM visited
    GROUP BY tk_hotel
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
  ) mv
  JOIN hotel h ON h.id = mv.tk_hotel
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
;
```

**Update**

If instead you want *all* the rows having the maximum number of visits, then that's a different kettle of fish.  Here's a way to express it:

```
WITH visit_count AS (
  SELECT tk_hotel, count(*) as visits
  FROM visited
  GROUP BY tk_hotel
)
SELECT h.name, vc.visits
FROM
  hotel h
  JOIN visit_count vc ON h.id = vc.tk_hotel
WHERE vc.visits = (SELECT MAX(visits) FROM visit_count)
```

Comment: First code seems good, but it only shows how much stayers were there. I want the name of hotel.
Second code is not working, or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: Sorry if I am bothering you, but this problem is driving me crazy and I want to solve it soooooooooo bad :/

Comment: Thanks buddy, now second one is working good! 
But when I test the first one I get that 2 or 3 hotels are having the same amount of visitors. Is possible to get all of them using MAX function and not ROWNUM?

And I would like if you can reply me here, if you are going to edit any part of code.
Also I wonder what are that H and MV in first row doing?

Comment: My apologies.  The Oracle syntax for performing a top-N query is a little different.  I have revised my answer.  Note in particular that Oracle syntax cannot express a limitation on the number of rows of an aggregate query, so the limit (based on `ROWNUM`) has to go in the outer query.

Comment: Yes It is working now, but can you read my upper question and help me with it too please?

Comment: Updated to answer the revised question.

Comment: The middle answer is good enough, but I want to add the OWNER of the hotel near the HOTEL name. Is that possible?
And what does **H**.hotel and **MV**.visits stands for?

Comment: I managed it by my self! THANK YOU for everything. Appreciate it!